# Cant get bot to select item off of supreme

Tags: python, bots

Im a beginner to python btw.

My goal is to build a very simple ACO bot for supreme. Although im running into a problem and I have not had much luck with solutions.
I tried to use `driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "")` but this is not exactly possible since the website constantly changes and I would need to always change the name of the product I want.

I tried to use "title", "ID" or "class" but there are multiple items with the same class, title and ID so that does not work. I read that someone doing the same thing as I, was using "PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT" so I tried driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Boxer Briefs"). I tried this by putting in "Boxer Briefs" to see if it would select the "Supreme/Hanes Boxer Briefs as a test. Unfortunately this also did not work, and it give me error saying

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message:
```

this is all of my code, like I said im a beginner and this is a very basic bot.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Safari()

url = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all"

driver.get(url)

driver.maximize_window()

click = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="nav-categories"]/li[10]/a')

click.click()

element = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Boxer Briefs")
```

any help would be really appreciated.

https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all

Comment: `JavaScript` needs some time to replace elements - when I use `time.sleep(1)` after `click()` then it works without problems. See also Selenium doc: [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html)

Answer (score 0):

`JavaScript` needs some time to replace elements - when I use `time.sleep(1)` after `click()` then it works without problems.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
import time

#driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

url = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all"
driver.get(url)

click = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="nav-categories"]/li[10]/a')
click.click()

time.sleep(1)

element = driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Boxer Briefs")
print(element.text)
```

See also Selenium doc: [Waits](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html) to create more universal code.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

#driver = webdriver.Safari()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.maximize_window()

url = "https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/all"
driver.get(url)

click = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="nav-categories"]/li[10]/a')
click.click()

try:
    element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Boxer Briefs"))
    )
    print(element.text)
except Exception as ex:    
    print('Exception:', ex)
```

Result:

```
Supreme®/Hanes® Boxer Briefs (2 Pack)
```

Tested with `Firefox` and `Chrome` on `Linux Mint 20` (based on `Ubuntu 21.04`)

---

**EDIT:**

If I `presence_of_all_elements_located` instead of `presence_of_element_located`

```
try:
    all_elements = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "Boxer Briefs"))
    )
    for element in all_elements:
        print(element.text)
except Exception as ex:    
    print('Exception:', ex)
```

the result is

```
Supreme®/Hanes® Boxer Briefs (2 Pack)
Supreme®/Hanes® Boxer Briefs (4 Pack)
Supreme®/Hanes® Boxer Briefs (4 Pack)
```

Comment: Hey there!, I appreciate the response but this didn't work. Could it be it be maybe because of my browser since im using safari? or could it maybe be because there are 3 items with " Boxer Briefs" in there name.

Comment: do you get error message? Did you try longer sleep? Some portals can send different HTML for different browser or for different devices (desktop, tablet, smartphone). You can use `driver.page_source` to get HTML from browser and check what you get - maybe you will see differece in HTML. I don't have Safari and I can't even install it on Linux. I tested it only with Firefox and Chrome on Linux Mint 20 (based on Ubuntu 21.04). If problem is only to get all 3 elements then you should use `presence_of_all_elements_located` instead of `presence_of_element_located` and later use `for`-loop.

Comment: Appreciate the response but I do not get an error it. I actually get (Process finished with exit code 0) which means it should be working but the bot is not clicking on the item. Once it reaches the page to select it. I downloaded chrome and will give it a spin. When you ran the bot on your computer did it reach the item selected on the website?

Comment: When I run it then it displays `Supreme®/Hanes® Boxer Briefs (2 Pack)`. If I use `presence_of_all_elements_located` instead of `presence_of_element_located` then I see 3 similar strings

Comment: strange is that it doesn't get error - it should get error if it couldn't find element and click it. Did you run it in console/terminal to see error messages?

Comment: yes it only shows the the Hanes boxer brief 2 pack. but when the bot is running in remote automation once it reaches the page to select the item it doesn't do it.

Comment: do you have this problem when you run it on local computer or external server? Server may have blocked access to page - some portals has servers on blacklist to block bots/spamers/hackers/et.